# How to remove deployed webapp in embedded Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using `apache-tomcat-8.5.4-embed` to load web application at runtime.
I have a requirement to stop web application when user requested to stop.
Is it possible to do, if yes please let me know the procedure!

Comment: You need make your question more clearly. What's the context when you use embed Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Uday , something worth a try are API's that are available (more specifically for ANT) in tomcat

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/ant/StopTask.html

I have  not tested the code below , but it is something you could try.

```
StopTask stopTask= new StopTask(); 
stopTask.setUsername("admin"); 
stopTask.setPassword("mypass"); 
stopTask.setUrl("http://server:port/manager";); 
stopTask.setPath("/my-webapp-context"); 
stopTask.execute();
```